# Multiple database connection issue in Spring project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I'm going to configure two databases connections in one spring project. Created two Data Source beans in following way.

```
   @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
        public BoneCPDataSource getDataSource() {

            ....
            ....
            return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
        public BoneCPDataSource getDataSource2() {

         ....
         ....

        return dataSource;
    }
```

This is the way I created entity managers.

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    ...
    em.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("entityManagerFactory");
    ...

    return em;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory2")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory2() {
    ...
    em.setDataSource(getDataSource2());
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("entityManagerFactory2");
    ...

    return em;
}
```

Then I Auto-wired above entity managers in Repository implementation classes and it works fine for non transactional data.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactory2")
@Qualifier(value = "entityManagerFactory2")
private EntityManager entityManager2;
```

Then created transactional managers in following way.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public JpaTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean(name = "transactionManager2")
@Qualifier("transactionManager2")
public JpaTransactionManager getTransactionManager2() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory2().getObject());

    return transactionManager;
}

    return transactionManager;
}
```

But the issue is, I can't insert or update tables using Bean transactionManager2 because I don't know the correct way to configure it.

But can insert or update using getTransactionManger only issue is can't configure second connection. Got this error.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you specifically need `@Primary` annotation in this context? and where do you configure in configurations that Spring should use `JpaTransactionManager ` returned by `getTransactionManager2()  ` over ` JpaTransactionManager ` returned by  `getTransactionManager()`. With `@Primary` you're instructing Spring to use `JpaTransactionManager ` from  `getTransactionManager()` over the other configured transaction manager.

Comment: Used @Primary annotation to set that transaction manage as default. That connection works fine. use this , `JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());`

Comment: But the problem is I cannot see  the place where you've set set `transactionManager2 ` as the transaction manager of whatever entitymanagerFactory, see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional

Comment: I updated related code parts in question please check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to use the second transaction manager, you need to annotate the service methods with:

```
@Transactional("transactionManager2")
public void insertPost(Post post) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. Got it . It works for me. As I learnt, using @Primary annotation  we can set that Bean as default transactional bean. So no need to specify transactional bean when use that one. We need this only when use specific transactional Bean. is that correct?

Comment: You mean the default transaction manager. The default one is named `transactionManager`, so no need to specify for that one.

Comment: It would seem to make sense to extend @Transactional to something that could select the proper transaction manager based on some environment variable. Not sure if that's possible. But hard coding this stuff seems pretty awkward